# White noise in time series models

Tags: time-series, arima, white-noise

In virtually every time series model out there (e.g. AR(1)), there is always the existence of a white noise term $\varepsilon_{t}$ like $y_{t} = \delta + \phi y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{t}$. I don't understand why its almost obligatory to stick in a 'white noise' term after every single time series model ever. For instance, if we fit an AR(1) model and try to forecast the next period, the conditional mean $E[y_{t+1}|y_{t}]$ gets rid of the white noise altogether, and for a sufficiently long forecast horizon we converge to the long-run mean $\frac{\delta}{1-\phi}$. I know I'm missing something quite fundamental here, but now it just seems like the sole purpose of $\varepsilon_{t}$ existing is for us to eventually cancel it out with an expectation operation. Why do we even care about including it?

My personal take on this is:

We have $y_{t}$ being the actual process that we don't know with certainty (hence there is noise $\varepsilon_{t}$), and the best we can do is to model the 'non-noise' portion as e.g. an AR(1), giving us $\hat{y_{t}} = \delta + \phi y_{t-1}$, and the reason for using white noise in particular, is because it is simply a convenient choice (i.e. it is an i.i.d process and hence adding it to the model does not violate the time invariant requirement for all time series models)

Is this a correct explanation?

Comment: How would you construct prediction intervals without some kind of probability model?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Without the $\varepsilon_t,$ everything is deterministic and there is no probability model available for fitting data or understanding the process.